# Uploading large files (greater than 10MB) from Android to PHP server

Tags: php, android, upload, shared

First of all sorry if this was already asked and sorted out. I really did a hard search and cant able to find a better solution.

Requirement: We are developing an Android application where we need to upload the video files to a folder in the web server. The web server is running in PHP.  The video files are very huge in size (more than 10 MB).  And the web server is hosted on a shared hosting server where they have PHP upload limit as 2MB.

I hope my requirement is very clear to understand.

We struggled for several days and found apache FTP could solve our problem.  After having few sleep less nights, we able to done the upload via FTP.  The problem in FTP is if the data (Internet / 3G) goes down then the FTP is stopped and it is not resuming after the data (Internet / 3G) is available.

Now we are back to square 1.  Searching again how to upload large files from android device to PHP server.

I need your advice on this.  Kindly help.

Thanks & Regards
Malai

Comment: I found a different post [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10276647/uploading-video-upto-50mb-to-the-server) which is exactly the same case as mine.  But that also not ended with the proper solution.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you will need to restrict your uploads to only ocurr while the user is on WiFi. You will want to do this anyway since most carriers are now on metered data plans; if the data connection is lost as in your scenario, then the user will be transmitting way more than just 10MB per upload, as each attempt is transmitting something.

Comment: Somebody didn't like my answer, I guess... Don't blame me if carriers don't have unlimited data plans anymore... :(

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your response. I agree with your point. But this app is ment for those who have unlimited plans. I am in India and I have unlimited data plan on my mobile. I wonder how facebook, YouTube are able to upload big files?...

Comment: I searched around for an answer for you, and I don't see a solution. The upload will stop if the network connection is lost. I didn't see where it was possible to pause an upload. Even uploading a picture to Facebook only gives me the option to cancel the process. Let me know if you find an answer.